# Is event_scheduler unavoidably disabled in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler, google-cloud-sql

I am just now discovering that Google Cloud SQL may not allow MySQL's event_scheduler to be activated, as activating it is a (restricted) SUPER privilege.

Currently

```
"select @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler;"

returns:

@@GLOBAL.event_scheduler
OFF

and

"set global event_scheduler=ON;"
```

returns:

```
*Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation*
```

This is really messing up a very scheduler-reliant production system I'm trying to migrate to the Cloud! Is the only work-around for this to implement Cron Jobs in GAE, or has anyone out there done anything clever with their SQL instance?

Comment: We can manually turn that on. Please contact us with the name of your instance at cloud-sql@google.com.

Comment: I had same problem, but I found solution here https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-flags now my question is will all replications will process event or only one and in case of only one will events get copied in replicas so in case fail switch replicas will process events ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event scheduler option can now be configured via flags: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags